# gcloud: command not found

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, gcloud

I got the followwing error:

> error failed pipeline on run pipeline gitlab
> The deployment of this job to Production did not succeed.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.1.0 (76984217)
  on ci 3wNvyH89
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on localhost.localdomain...
Getting source from Git repository
00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/3wNvyH89/0/root/yogesh1/.git/
Checking out 668d7d24 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
bash: line 125: gcloud: command not found
Running after_script
00:00
Running after script...
$ rm /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the image you are using in your `gitlab-ci.yml`.

For instance, in the article "[How to Setup Gitlab CI Pipeline For Google Cloud App Engine?](https://tapendradev.medium.com/how-to-setup-gitlab-ci-pipeline-for-google-cloud-app-engine-ee2d45569013)" from [Tapendra Dev](https://twitter.com/tapendradev), he is using:

```yaml
image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
  - master
  script:
  - echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
  - gcloud --quiet --project $PROJECT_ID app deploy app.yaml dispatch.yaml
```

Which means `gcloud` is already installed and in the `$PATH`.